# I am having a problem with Discord.js code I have not found a solution

Tags: javascript, discord, bots

It gives an error that when I input the command -play music it gives this:

C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\commands\play.js:8
const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
^

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'voice')
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\commands\play.js:8:45)
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\main.js:37:37)
    at Client.emit (node:events:527:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\Messag    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSock    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:527:28)
PS C:\Users\User\Desktop\Discord Bot JS>
```

heres the code

```
const ytdl = require('ytdl-core');
const ytSearch = require('yt-search');
 
module.exports = {
    name: 'play',
    description: 'Joins and plays a video from youtube',
    async execute(client, message, args) {
        const voiceChannel = message.member.voice.channel;
 
        if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
        const permissions = voiceChannel.permissionsFor(message.client.user);
        if (!permissions.has('CONNECT')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!permissions.has('SPEAK')) return message.channel.send('You dont have the correct permissins');
        if (!args.length) return message.channel.send('You need to send the second argument!');
 
        const validURL = (str) =>{
            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex.test(str)){
                return false;
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        }
 
        if(validURL(args[0])){
 
            const  connection = await voiceChannel.join();
            const stream  = ytdl(args[0], {filter: 'audioonly'});
 
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
                message.channel.send('leaving channel');
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***Your Link!***`)
 
            return
        }
 
        
        const connection = await voiceChannel.join();
 
        const videoFinder = async (query) => {
            const videoResult = await ytSearch(query);
 
            return (videoResult.videos.length > 1) ? videoResult.videos[0] : null;
 
        }
 
        const video = await videoFinder(args.join(' '));
 
        if(video){
            const stream  = ytdl(video.url, {filter: 'audioonly'});
            connection.play(stream, {seek: 0, volume: 1})
            .on('finish', () =>{
                voiceChannel.leave();
            });
 
            await message.reply(`:thumbsup: Now Playing ***${video.title}***`)
        } else {
            message.channel.send('No video results found');
        }
    }
}
```

I got the code from a youtube tutorial and I looked for many solutions that eventually did not work.

Comment: `message.member` is `undefined`. You can try optional chaining:  `message.member?.voice.channel`

Answer (score 0):

As @JBallin said you have to use `message.member?.voice.channel` instead of `message.member.voice.channel`.

The **?** in the `message.member?.voice.channel` will handle the small problem itself.

Comment: i tried it and now it gave me an error :
if (!voiceChannel) return message.channel.send('You need to be in a channel to execute this command!');
                                                  ^

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'send')

Comment: it seems 
that 'send' is not defined

Comment: Can you `console.log(message);` and share it?

Comment: sorry, where am i supposed to add it?

Comment: In your question

Comment: which part? sorry if im like dumb i havent slept for 2 days now

Comment: Anyways, can you share the link the that YouTube video where you got the above code? And share it in the comment section.